# How can I read attributes of a self closing tag using SimpleXML (PHP)

Tags: php, parsing, tags, simplexml

I have a XML file containing, among other tags, some self closing tags.

```
<tagname attr1="foo1" attr2="foo2" />
```

I use  PHP's simplexml to load the XML file into a object.
So far so good.

The problem is with the self closing tags. (print_r returns an empty object)

I cannot access their attributes.

**====UPDATE====**

It worked this way:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xml->tagname['attr1'];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use SimpleXMLElement from  the PHP Library, related to SimpleXML

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

```
public SimpleXMLElement SimpleXMLElement::attributes ([ string $ns = NULL [, bool $is_prefix = false ]] )
```